# Serving static React app from server, crashing on refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have made a React app which is hosted on the same machine as my API server as guided by [this tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/).

My directories are set up in such way that

```
- root
  - server.js (entry for the API server)
  - app (for all back-end stuff)
  - client (directory for React app)
    - public (static files used in the front-end)
    - src (for all front-end stuff)
    - build (directory containing static build)
      - index.html (entry for front-end)
      - ... (other bundled stuff)
```

And I am serving a static copy of my React app in below method.

```
// server.js

const app = express();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.use('/api', routes); // for API routes
```

I am having a problem where, when I boot this up locally, (with `NODE_ENV=production`) everything smooth and page refreshes do not break the app.

However, after I have deployed this to Elastic Beanstalk, page refreshes break the app with this html error message being displayed in the browser.

`Cannot GET /{whichever url path I had prior to refresh}`

I could see in the logs that browser tried to send a request to the server with **GET /{url_pathname}**

I initially suspected something going funny with having both React router and Express router but then again, I am confused why this is not consistent with the case in the localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a react app that basically runs on a single index file, then your middleware router should have a catch-all route that always points to that index file somewhere.

```
 app.get('/*',(req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
 })
```

Please note that the current example is dependent on the `path` module...So:

```
import path from 'path'
// or
const path = require('path')
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out and accept it as soon as things start working as expected. Can you also explain what the possible causes for the inconsistent behaviors are between the localhost and the deployment?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NGINX, you need to update the configuration file located at
**/etc/nginx/sites-available**

```
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
        }
```

Or this if your app is not located in the default directory, for example "app-location" you would get this.

```
location /app-location {
  root /var/www;
  index  index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /app-location/index.html;
}
```

And restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: I was not able to find `sites-available` directory in my ec2 instance when I SSH'ed inside